# Distinct vs setResultTransformer() in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In JPA i am using `setResultTransformer()` to filter repeated data because I have read that using `distinct` on query which return large dataset is reduce the performance. But my friend saying that `setResultTransformer()` will take java heap memory in case of large dataset which will cause to outofmemory exception. Is this right?

Comment: Which result transformer do you use?

Comment: typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecif‌​ication.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)` will take a lot of memory of course. And it will not have a better performance than `distinct` using HQL or SQL.

The reason is that Hibernate will load all data from a database and process it in the memory using `CriteriaSpecif‌​ication.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY`. Database can use some optimization to do `distinct` itself.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the comment. If you have any proof plz post it also. I think hibernate is smart enough to handle memory utilization in efficient way using session or any other thing.

Comment: @viveksharma To process data Hibernate need to retrieve it by network for an example. You can use transformer too. It is ok. But It is incorrect to think that it has more performance.